# Passing a function to arrayfun

Tags: matlab, function

If I pass an anonymous function to `arrayfun` as follows:

```
arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g\\pi', x/pi), [0 6 7 8], 'uni', 0)
```

I get the following result:

```
ans = 
    '0\pi'    '1.9\pi'    '2.2\pi'    '2.5\pi'
```

However, if I declare a separate function:

```
function y = sprint_func_0(x)
    sprintf('%.2g\\pi', x/pi)
end
```

and pass it to `arrayfun`:

```
arrayfun(@(x)sprint_func_0(x), [0 6 7 8], 'uni', 0)
```

The result is:

```
ans =
    0\pi

ans =
    1.9\pi

ans =
    2.2\pi

ans =
    2.5\pi
```

Why do I get one output in the first case and many outputs in the second case? This is probably stupid, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case the anonymous function returns a string, so `arrayfun` returns a cell array of strings.

In the second case the function does not assign a value to the output parameter `y` (essentially printing the output of `sprintf` to the command window).

If you modify the function `sprint_func_0` to:

```
function y = sprint_func_0(x)
    y = sprintf('%.2g\\pi', x/pi); %// Note the assignment to y
end
```

you should get the same result.

Comment: Is it just me or does it not seem amazing that declaring `function y= ...` without `y` being defined anywhere in the body of the function does not return an error??

Comment: @TryHard In general it is definately bad practice, though it needs not result in an error because `y` can for example be loaded from a mat file. In this case however, the function will only run without errors if you call it with zero output arguments. Indeed a bit strange as I always assumed matlab calls a function with 1 output argument by default and assign it to ans if it is not specified where it should go.

Comment: It is indeed strange how `arrayfun` performs the actual function calls, because the output argument of each individual function call shouldn't be related to whether there is or there is not an output variable for `arrayfun`. Then again, who knows...